flutter run gives error: Build failed with an exception
when I try to run with flutter run it throws error:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Failed to create Jar file C:\Users\admin.gradle\caches\jars-9\28753865c79b16547db54c3e683584af\gradle-1.0.0.jar.


org.gradle.api.GradleException: Failed to create Jar file C:\Users\admin.gradle\caches\jars-9\28753865c79b16547db54c3e683584af\gradle-1.0.0.jar.


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.


Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 26s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                            147.6s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
I tried deleting the .gradle directory and tired flutter clean
I'm expecting to run this project on emulator in android studio

Can you explain the issue more in details

Have you tried flutter clean command? then try to run again and see if that help.

What are the result with Flutter doctor command

Try to open the android folder with Android Studio and wait for Gradle building
